# How to display a set of questions using while loop in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have total 10 questions with their options in database like this:
 id question    option1    option2    option3

Below is my code which selects 1 question randomly and displays it on webpage with its options. Now I want that five random question should be displayed one after another in form on webpage with their respective options. How can I do that?

```
<?php
include_once("db_conx.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM mymake ORDER BY RAND()";
$query=mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $id = $row["id"];
                    $question = $row["question"];
                    $option1 = $row["option1"];
                    $option2 = $row["option2"];
                    $option3 = $row["option3"];
        }
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.ask {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
input{
    background: transparent;
}
option{ color: #C03;
}
placeholder {color: #C03;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="ask">
<form>
<input type="text" name="q1" placeholder="<?php echo $question;?>"  size="82">
<select>
<option value="<?php echo $option1; ?>"><?php echo $option1; ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo $option2; ?>"><?php echo $option2; ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo $option3; ?>"><?php echo $option3; ?></option>

</select>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is your existing code. What changes did you make in it to try to show five questions in a loop?

Comment: i tried for(i=0;i>5;i++) followed by while loop and then increment i. but it is showing error.

Comment: In that case, instead of pasting this code, you should paste the one you tried along with the error you get when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your current code actually loops through all of the questions in your database, re-assigning your questions and options each time it goes through them. Then, on the last time through, uses those variables to make a form.

In your while loop you could make the variables `$question`, `$option`, etc.. arrays and then loop through them in your code 5 times.

I made a quick change to your code just looping through your existing query but outputting HTML code instead of re-assigning your variables.

```
<?php
include_once("db_conx.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mymake ORDER BY RAND()";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.ask {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
input { background: transparent; }
option { color: #C03; }
placeholder { color: #C03; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="ask">
<form>
<?php
if ($numrows > 0){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <input type="text" name="q<?php echo $row["id"];?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row["question"];?>"  size="82">
    <select>
      <option value="<?php echo $row["option1"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["option1"]; ?></option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row["option2"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["option2"]; ?></option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row["option3"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["option3"]; ?></option>
    </select>;
<?php
  }
}
?>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Its working fine,..Thankyou Mr. Ryan.Your explanation notes made the things understandable to me(I am new programming). one more question i want to add here. When this form will be displayed on  user profile, he needs to answer them and then it will be inserted into their database. How can that be done. I havent used array earlier.

Comment: @ShailendraHuntArya The form you created needs to POST this data to a PHP page which will validate the data (make sure it's safe and doesn't contain code that will try to disrupt your code). Then you will need to `INSERT` it into a database table you will have created. There are lots of tutorials on the web for this kind of thing, but the logic I use above should guide you well enough. If this answer helped, don't forget to mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I know how to insert the data normally but not with loops. Can you just tell me in two or three lines how to get that in php. Normally we do, [CODE]<?php if(isset('submit')) { $ques=$_POST['question'];$ans=$_POST['answer'];}  ?>[/CODE]. How should i start in this case. please

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bothering database result randomize we can handle it ourself. We can take a 1D array of questions (let q_list[]) and another multi-dimentional array like q_arr[ 'question' ][ 'id' ], q_arr[ 'question' ][ 'option1' ], q_arr[ 'question' ][ 'option2' ], q_arr[ 'question' ][ 'option3' ]. Here it is:

```
// declare arrays
q_list = array();
q_arr = arrar( q_list );

// fetch results
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    q_list[ $i++ ] = $row[ "question" ];
    q_arr[ $row["question"] ][ 'id' ] = $row[ 'id' ];
    q_arr[ $row["question"] ][ 'option1' ] = $row[ 'option1' ];
    q_arr[ $row["question"] ][ 'option2' ] = $row[ 'option2' ];
    q_arr[ $row["question"] ][ 'option3' ] = $row[ 'option3' ];
}
```

Here we using shuffle function is a bit easier. It shuffles all the values of an array randomly. [ref: Php Shuffle Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_shuffle.asp)

Now, shuffle "q_list" array, and just print like as:

```
shuffle( q_list );
$i = 0;
while( $i < 5 ){
    echo "Question: " . $q_list[ $i ] ];
    echo "ID: "      . q_arr[ $q_list[ $i ] ][ 'id' ];
    echo "Option1: " . q_arr[ $q_list[ $i ] ][ 'option1' ];
    echo "Option2: " . q_arr[ $q_list[ $i ] ][ 'option2' ];
    echo "Option3: " . q_arr[ $q_list[ $i ] ][ 'option3' ];
    $i++;
}
```